# aspx file cannot be found in project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on asp.net. There is a page tested on my localhost. This project is transferred to me by previous developer. The page is "localhost:4472/TblQualClients/List.aspx" and it is working fine, but I could not find this aspx file in any of my folders; and in another aspx document, I found there is a  pointing to this page, but it is shown as "File 'TblQualClients/List.aspx' was not found".

Can anyone help with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could create a new project and then add that page to it.

Comment: That's odd. If you View Source in a browser, there's a line like: <form name="form1" method="post" action="WebForm1.aspx" What name is there?

Comment: The code is: <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="List.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm"> @user814064

Comment: It seems like there should be a List.ASPX somewhere then unless you're using something like Umbraco or some URL rewriting scheme.

Comment: I have checked web.config, but could not find any thing about rewriting this URL @MelanciaUK

Comment: Just in case, have a look in the Global.asax too.

Comment: Hi MelanciaUK, I found "routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx") {
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert|ListAll" }),
            Model = model
        });" in the Global.asax file. It may be related to my case, but I can't understand it yet. Thanks. @MelanciaUK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project uses `Dynamic Data`.

*ASP.NET Dynamic Data lets you create extensible data-driven Web applications by inferring at run time the appearance and behavior of data entities from the database schema and deriving UI behavior from it.
Dynamic Data supports scaffolding, which is a way to automatically generate Web pages for each table in the database. Scaffolding lets you create a functional Web site for viewing and editing data based on the schema of the data. You can easily customize scaffolding elements or create new ones to override the default behavior.
You can also enable dynamic behavior in existing or new Web applications without using scaffolding. In that case, you specify how and when Dynamic Data should infer UI elements from the data source without using scaffolding for the entire Web site.*

Taken from the MSD website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452.aspx

Also, refer to this article to understand how it works:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2008/06/23/how-to-add-dynamic-data-to-an-existing-web-site.aspx